# PHP-file_get_contents: Unable to check two file_get_contents in a single if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, file-get-contents

I am running two `api` calls through the same if statement to make sure they both return values. A form of error checking.

They both pass the test, however the first `file_get_contents` cannot be accessed or decoded by `json_decode`.

```
    if (
      $exchangeRates = (file_get_contents('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates'))
      &&
      $data = (file_get_contents('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD'))
    ){

    $json1 = json_decode($exchangeRates, true);
    $json2 = json_decode($data, true);

    return [$json1, $json2];
}
```

The above returns:

```
[
 1,
 {
  "data": 
   {
   "base": "BTC",
   "currency": "USD",
   "amount": "3532.335"
   }
 }
]
```

When I refer to individual values in `$json1` they return null.

When the url's are entered into a url manually they both return the appropriate JSON.

Can only one `file_get_contents` be used per if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), `&&` is on higher priority so it executes `get_file_contents` first, then use `&&` and returns to $exchangeRates. Finally, $exchangeRates is the boolean. you should use () correctly in this case:

```
    if (
($exchangeRates = file_get_contents('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates'))
    &&
($data = file_get_contents('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD'))
) {

    $json1 = json_decode($exchangeRates, true);
    $json2 = json_decode($data, true);

    return [$json1, $json2];
}
```

Comment: "When in doubt, divide by () and conquer" -- Confucius

Comment: And be aware. That the response could be still no valid json. It could fetch but fail to parse.